# Git rm can't find .sass-cache folder

Tags: git, caching, sass

I'm trying to remove my everything in my .sass-cache folder from git. `/app/assets/stylesheets/.sass-cache` is the full path of the folder. I believe `git rm -r --cached folder` is the command for removing the contents of a folder from git, but when I cd into `app/assets/stylesheets` and run this:

```
git rm -r --cached .sass-cache
```

I get the following error:

> fatal: pathspec '.sass-cache' did not match any files

so I think the "." at the beginning is making it look for a file. Am I on the right track at least?

Comment: This just means the path `app/assets/stylesheets/.sass-cache` does not exist in the index (neither as a directory containing files, nor as a file). You can view the entire index contents (all the files that will go into the next commit you make) using `git ls-files --staged`, but note that this prints a LOT of stuff in a big repository.

Comment: @torek But when I open git gui there are thousands of app/assets/stylesheets/.sass-cache files, so doesn't that mean that it's in the index?

Comment: If `git rm --cached` says they are not in the index, they are definitely not in the index. Perhaps Git-GUI is showing you files that are in the *work-tree*. Any file that is in the work-tree but not in the index is, by definition, an *untracked file*, and Git in general complains about them unless you tell it to stop complaining, by listing those files (e.g., by path-name pattern in a `.gitignore` file). Note that `.gitignore` is only effective on *untracked* files: files that are in the index cannot be ignored.

Comment: BTW it's a very odd if you're literally typing in `app/assets/stylesheets/.sass-cache` but Git says `.sass-cache` *without* the `app/assets/stylesheets/` part in front. Are you sure there's no accidental white-space or some such in between these names?

Comment: @torek My mistake, that was the error message from the stylesheets folder.

Comment: @torek And thank you for that information, I had a total misconception about how the whole system worked. I added `app/assets/stylesheets/.sass-cache/*` to my gitignore and now the sass-cache files no longer show up in my git gui. If you add that as an answer I can accept it!

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though you already don't have the files in your index (aka staging-area, aka cache).  When a file *isn't* in the index, it won't be in the *next* commit you make, and `git rm --cached` cannot remove it from the index / staging-area / cache (that it's not in).  Note that `git commit` always makes *new* commits from whatever is currently in the index—hence the index typically contains a copy of every file that you just checked out from some commit.

Git will, however, *complain* about files that exist in your *work-tree* that are not in your index, saying that such file are *untracked*.  (Note that these files are normally also *not* in your current commit.<sup>1</sup>)  To make Git specifically *not* complain about such files, you can list them—by path name, or pattern—in a `.gitignore` file.  In this case, adding either:

```
app/assets/stylesheets/.sass-cache/*
```

or just:

```
app/assets/stylesheets/.sass-cache/
```

to your top-level `.gitignore` file, creating that file if necessary, will suffice to tell Git to stop complaining about such files (and suppress automatically *adding* them to the index if you use an "add all files" operation).

---

<sup>1</sup>Running `git checkout branch` extracts, into your index and work-tree, all the files that are contained in the *tip commit* on the named branch.  Therefore a file that is now in the work-tree *and* in the index, must be there because it was in the commit.  A file that is now in the work-tree but *not* in the index, must have been there before you ran `git checkout branch`.

This general rule fails, of course, if you `git checkout branch` and then successfully run `git rm --cached file`.  In this particular case, the named *`file`* *was* in the tip commit, and *was* in both the index and the work-tree.  You then removed it from the index, leaving it in the work-tree.  The *next commit you make* will *omit* the file, but it is still in the current commit, and `git status` will show that *`file`* is to be deleted by the next commit (which is true: it's in the current commit, and won't be in the next one, so the difference between the current commit and the next one will include deleting file *`file`*).